# Fast retreival of single-point bicubic interpolation from a raster?

Tags: python, raster, interpolation

I have a raster data set with a grid size of 100m. I want to get information from it for a single point within the grid, using bicubic interpolation to use a bit more of the information from the data at each point.

I could do this manually by selecting the 16 closest grid points, and then calculating the interpolation manually, but I'm wondering if there are already tools that exist that do this. I don't want to calculate multiple values (e.g. re-sampling/re-gridding), I just want the one point, and I want to be able to get it fairly quickly (e.g. minimise data loading)

I'm working in python, and currently use a mix of gdal, rasterio, and xarray.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo.. I know how stack exchange works. There is no current code (except a simple existing nearest-neighbour selection function, which is not really relevant). I don't really see how a code snippet would make the question clearer in this case.

Comment: @PolyGeo To be clear, this is not a coding question. I can confidently figure out how to do it myself. However it seems like a tool for which a library function is likely to exist already, but I have searched to no avail, and I am wondering if I am thinking about the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: It sounds like you have existing code that you are trying to improve by inclusion of an additional tool/library.  If you're seeking a software recommendation then there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.  If you include a codes snippet that illustrates how you you are currently doing it, or trying to do it, then that helps to "pay it forward" and would enable me to vote to re-open your question.

Comment: Fair enough. I give up. There is no current code. When I do write code for it, I won't need the question anymore. There is zero chance that anyone on Software Recs would have a better idea how to answer this than someone on a GIS-specific stack exchange.

Comment: Questions seeking ideas for doing GIS tasks are always welcome in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129532/discussion-between-naught101-and-polygeo).